# How to send external form in backbone and rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, backbone.js, salesforce

I have a app with backbone in frontend and rails in backend. They are connected via api. I need implement form which will send to salesforce **without refresh page**. But I don't know how to do it.

The form looks like:

```
<form action="https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToCase?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">

    <input type=hidden name="orgid" value="xxxxxxx"> 
    <input type=hidden name="retURL" value="xxx">

    <input type=hidden name="xxx" id="xxx" value="xxx">

    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input id="name" maxlength="80" name="name" size="20" type="text" required=true/><br>

    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" required=true/><br>

    <label for="description">Question</label>
    <textarea name="description" required=true></textarea>

    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Firstly, I tried to directly send the form via `ajax`, however, the js is not allowed to send the external url request. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` will raise.

Then, I tried to send the request to backend firstly, and then send the post request to `salesforce`. However, I don't know how to do it in `backbone`.

Where to put the logic in `backbone`? In `View`, or `Model`, or `Collection`?

Should I create a separate controller in rails to handle the request? Or just an action method is enough?

Could someone tell me the best solution and provide me a simple example?

Thanks.

Comment: If salesforce API isn't allowing cross-domain requests, you won't be able to do it with JavaScript. If there's nothing to do for salesforce to accept your domain, you may put the form in an iframe which _won't refresh_ the whole page on submit.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Thanks for answer. It's not salesforce api forbid cross-domain, it's our app.

Comment: If you're making an AJAX request to `webto.salesforce.com` and it gives an error about `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, it means that `webto.salesforce.com` is not configured to respond to cross-domain request. CORS is a server side configuration.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?